# Encryptr on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I try to run Encryptr[1] on ubuntu - I am getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/Encryptr: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I installed libxrenderer1 and libxrenderer-dev

[1] https://encryptr.org/

Comment: Did you install the 32-bit build of Encryptr on a 64-bit install of Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks a lot - that was the problem - if you do it ans answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed the wrong architecture build for your system. You've installed the 32-bit build and are on a 64-bit system, but do not have the required 32-bit libraries installed. You will need to install the required 32-bit libraries, or switch to using the 64-bit build of the package.